# Defining a Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>

Tags: c#

I am trying to define a static readonly dictionary of dictionary object in C# and am not sure if this is the correct way to store an object that consists of 1 key and 2 values. This code doesn't work but it shows the logic of what I am trying to achieve.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> StudentMapping = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>
        {
            {"Liam", new Dictionary<string, int>{"broadway", 1}},
            {"Emily", new Dictionary<string, int>{"math", 1}}
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered creating a custom class instead of using an inner dictionary? If you only need a string and an integer (= "2 values"), that could be enough, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> am not sure if this is the correct way to store an object that consists of **1 key and 2 values**

To store 2 `int` values for each `String` key, use a `ValueTuple` of `(int, int)` for `TValue`:

[C# has special-case syntax for using `ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples):

```cs
private static readonly Dictionary<string,(int broadway, int math)> StudentMapping = new Dictionary<string,(int broadway, int math)>
{
    { "Liam" , ( broadway: 1, math: 1 ) },
    { "Emily", ( broadway: 1, math: 1 ) },
}
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that "Emily" doesn't have a broadway and "Liam" doesn't have a math feature. Those subject names are unique to each student

Comment: but I see the logic and can make this work. Thank you @Dai

Answer (score 0):

When you've reached the point where you're nesting dictionaries as data storage it's probably time for a class

```
public class Student{

    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Dictionary<string, int> Grades {get;set;}
}
```

And the usage perhaps:

```
var students = new List<Student>(){
  new(){ 
      Name = "Emily", 
      Grades = new () { ["math"] = 1 , [ "english"] = 2 }   
}};
```